# Is there any function or method to clear the running console in python program?

Tags: python, cmd, console, python-3.8

I am using pyCharm pro on windows.

I tried almost all the methods but no one is working.

I tried these functions too:

```
def screen_clear():
   # for mac and linux(here, os.name is 'posix')
   if os.name == 'posix':
      _ = os.system('clear')
   else:
      # for windows platfrom
      _ = os.system('cls')
```

with this py code

```
i = 10
while i > 0:
    print("X"*i)
    i -= 1
    sleep(1)
    screen_clear()
```

and its giving this output:
[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRggs.png)

Comment: would just pressing enter to get everything out of viw work for you? after all even with clear commands, you can see previous outputs when scrolling up

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Windows Terminal](//github.com/microsoft/terminal), this works:

```
print('\x1bc')
```

To respond to the comments. I just tested this again with a pristine virtual
machine under [Windows 10 1903](//superuser.com/questions/1108085), also using Windows Terminal 1.4 and
Python 3.9, and it works as expected.

Comment: No its not working 
its showing  back arrow with c like that  <-c when I print('\x1bc')

Comment: Yes I am using Windows Terminal

Comment: @SajeelHassan what Windows are you using - see update